# How to implement a F to C, and C to F button

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently building a weather app and this is the final step in my journey. My main problem here is that child components don't affect the parent component and I can't seem to get around this difficulty. I currently have a component called Weather which looks like: (only copying the render function)

```
render() {
    if (this.state.loaded1 && this.state.loaded2) {
      return (
        <div id="app" className={`${this.state.stClass}`}>
          <h1>WeatherWatch</h1>
          <Search submit={this.search} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col weather">
                <Button
                  temp={this.state.weather.temperature}
                  min={this.state.weather.min}
                  max={this.state.weather.max}
                  f1={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp1}
                  f2={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp2}
                  f3={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp3}
                  f4={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp4}
                  f5={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp5}
                  f6={this.state.forecast.forecastTemp6}
                />
                <WeatherIcon
                  description={this.state.weather.description}
                  timestamp={this.state.weather.date}
                  timezone={this.state.weather.timezone}
                  sunrise={this.state.weather.sunrise}
                  sunset={this.state.weather.sunset}
                />
                <div className="col description">
                  {this.state.weather.description}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col date">
                <div className="city">{this.state.weather.city}</div>
                <HumanDate
                  timestamp={this.state.weather.date}
                  timezone={this.state.weather.timezone}
                />
                <HumanDate2
                  timestamp={this.state.weather.date}
                  timezone={this.state.weather.timezone}
                />
                <span className="temp">{this.state.weather.temperature}ºC</span>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col">
                    <div className="min-max">
                      {this.state.weather.min}ºC | {this.state.weather.max}
                      ºC
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

(etc)

Notice the Button component. It looks like this;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    unit: "metric"
  };

  fahrenheit = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: "imperial",
      imperialTemp: this.props.temp * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialMin: this.props.min * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialMax: this.props.max * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF1: this.props.f1 * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF2: this.props.f2 * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF3: this.props.f3 * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF4: this.props.f4 * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF5: this.props.f5 * (9 / 5) + 32,
      imperialF6: this.props.f6 * (9 / 5) + 32
    });
  };

  celsius = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: "metric",
      metricTemp: (this.props.temp - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricMin: (this.props.min - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricMax: (this.props.max - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF1: (this.props.f1 - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF2: (this.props.f2 - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF3: (this.props.f3 - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF4: (this.props.f4 - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF5: (this.props.f5 - 32) * (5 / 9),
      metricF6: (this.props.f6 - 32) * (5 / 9)
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.unit === "metric") {
      return (
        <div>
          <button className="fahr" onClick={this.fahrenheit}>
            ºF
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <button className="celsius" onClick={this.celsius}>
            ºC
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Button;
```

It's a toggle that works but the temperatures don't change precisely because the props of this component don't affect the parent component.

Any suggestions as to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

you should be passing a callback function to the button which then changes the state of the parent component.

```
convertUnits = (type) => {
  if (type === 'celcius') {
    ...do conversions to celcius
  } else {
    ...do conversions to fahrenheit
  }
}
```

then pass it to your button:

```
<Button
  convertUnits={this.convertUnits}
/>
```

and in your button you call it with the corresponding value.

Comment: "and in your button you call it with the corresponding value" can you explain it better what you mean by this? Sorry

Comment: So in the `<Button/>` component it will be a prop, so use that function in your click handler in the button component.

Comment: I'm sorry, your solution doesn't work. It says that ```celsius``` and ```fahrenheit``` are not defined.